# Finding Duplicates and Creating a column which points out the duplicates in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------|------|------|
| m    | n    | o    |
| m    | q    | e    |
| a    | b    | r    |
```

- Let's say I have a `pandas DataFrame` as shown above. Notice the `col1` values are same for the `0th` and `1st` row. Is there way to find all the `duplicate entries` on the dataframe based on `Col1` only.
- Additionally i wold also like to add another column say `is_duplicate` which would say `True` for all the duplicate instances of my DataFrame and `False` otherwise.

> Note: I want to find the duplicates based only on basis of the value in `Col1` the other columuns can be or  might not be duplicates, They should'nt be taken into consideration.

Comment: df.col1.duplidated()?

Comment: Thanks for the hint .. I did it it like-so:  df["is_duplicate"] = df.col1.duplicated()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :

```
df["is_duplicate"] = df.Col1.duplicated(keep=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

[.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) has exactly that functionality:

```
df['is_duplicate'] = df.duplicated('Col1')
```